# Question about android navigation architecture component

Tags: android, architecture, navigation, components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a question. I'm using android navigation architecture components, using bottom navigation view with singl activity. How can I make a fragment open only once? Even if the button that causes this fragment is clicked several times?
How to make a fragment to be added to the back stack only once?
I created a test project for try it

xml navigation_test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/test_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="ru.artem_nr.navigation_test.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFrag"
            app:destination="@id/navigation"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/secondFrag"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false" />
    </fragment>
    <navigation android:id="@+id/navigation"
        app:startDestination="@id/secondFrag">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/secondFrag"
            android:name="ru.artem_nr.navigation_test.SecondFrag"
            android:label="fragment_second"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

main_activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
       implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
public Toolbar toolbar;
public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
public NavController navController;
public NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupNavigation();
}

private void setupNavigation() {

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.garden_nav_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return (boolean) NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawerLayout);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    int id = menuItem.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            navController.navigate(R.id.navigation);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

fragments - just a blank

Comment: Your question says bottom navigation, but your code uses a `NavigationView`. Which is it that you're trying to use? Are trying to handle the case where the user reselects the item in the menu that is already selected?

Comment: it's does't matter what kind of navigation I use. In my real project bottom nav view, but I created a test project as I said. In drawer layout the the same problem.
Yes, you are right, I'm trying to handle it. If user reselects some fragment it's going to back stack. 
How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124538620#comment3), `BottomNavigationView` offers a `OnNavigationItemReselectedListener` that takes precedence over the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` set by `NavigationUI`:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationReselectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNavigationItemReselected(MenuItem item) {
            // By doing nothing, we ignore reselection events
        }
    });
```

`NavigationView` does not offer the same interface, as per [this other issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124398826), so you'd want to [copy the default behavior](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/navigation/ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI.java#418) (note that it calls `NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected()` and not just call `navigate()` directly, unlike your code) and add your own check for `isChecked()` to guard against reselection.

Comment: so, at the moment the platform have no default solution of this problem? if I rigth undestend

Comment: @АртемАртемов - correct, each component is entirely independent from one another.

Comment: I'm tryed to use NavOptions.Builder for bot nav view. It's helps for many times clicks on one fragment, but it's doesn't helps for a situation, when I clicks on different icons   in turn many times. Creates big back stack, now I see one way - create isChecked(), as you said, but it's not good decision in a big project, because we need to create isChecked() method for every fragment.

Comment: You should not be setting a `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on bottom nav - the default `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController()` does the correct thing.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm having similar issues with global actions while using drawerlayout. I have 3 top-level destinations (one for each drawer item). These just stack on top of each other. Using launchSingleTop doesn't do anything. Furthermore, enter/exit animations not working for global actions. Is this a bug? Known issue? WAI? If not, where to report?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the fragment as "SingleTop".

There is an option on the menu in the right hand side of the navigation graph editor view to do this, below the animation options.

Alternatively you can set it programmatically through the NavOptions.Builder class, using the setLaunchSingleTop(true) method as detailed in the link below:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavOptions.Builder#setLaunchSingleTop(kotlin.Boolean)

So your on select method should look like:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem){
NavOptions.Builder builder = new NavOptions.Builder()
.setLaunchSingleTop(true);

NavOptions options = builder.build();
navController.navigate(item.getItemId(), null, options);
```

Comment: You mean you tried to do it programmatically using NavOptions.Builder? If you share your code, we might be able to spot an issue for you

Comment: no, I did it in interface. I created a test project for try it

Comment: try programmatically?

Comment: yeah, thank you for your answer, but it's works not for all situations

Comment: you can only setLaunchSingleTop() for actions, not for fragments - so you cannot "declare a fragment as SingleTop" although I wish you could!